Can a carbon crank be safely put into a vice?
I bought a second-hand bike. I prepared everything, had something also fixed by a bike shop, only just had to replace the SPD pedals for my pedals when I found out they are stuck. I managed to remove the right one, but the left one remains. I used all my might with two hands on one crank and a foot on the pedal wrench, but no luck. I applied some heat, but cannot apply more as it would destroy the carbon fiber.
Can I remove the crank arm (SRAM, likely X01) from the bike and put it into a vice to try to use a hex nut on the biggest ratchet I have? Or should I use some other method less endangering the carbon-fiber crank arm instead?

I know it's a silly question, but are you turning it in the correct direction? Left pedal is left-threaded. I think I know which way to turn the pedal to undo it, but if I got a £ for each time I got it wrong, I'd be rich. Conversely, everytime I get it wrong, I genuinely believe the pedal is stuck... so worth checking.

Yes, surely. If it is left hand threaded, then I am applying it correctly. It can be confusing because one screws it inside, when using the hex socket, but it is just the mirror image of the right one. On the rear side press down.

Did you manage to undo it in the end?

@ArtGertner No, I didn't do any more attempt since. I cannot do most of them here, I can only do them in the countryside with a better workshop and potentially with someone else helping me for more force or leverage. For now I bought SPD cleats.

@MattMorgan No "vice" is correct - eg see this dictionary (search for "tool" on that page)!

@psmears lol TIL.  Looks like that's standard in the UK, but in the US we use "vise."  I think either is OK then!

@MattMorgan For what it's worth, I've always used "vise" for the benchtop tool and "vice" for a chronic bad habit. Regional differences are very interesting.

Presuming the pedals have an internal Allen wrench flat on the end of the spindle, the safest way is take an L-wrench of the correct size and clamp that into the vise with the short part of the L sticking up in the center of the jaws and the long part clamped in the jaws. From there I use a Park FFS on the crank in these situations, though a piece of PVC can work on a left if it's an "arm only" left and not one that's integral with the spindle.
Getting leverage on the bike by using a toe strap to attach the opposite crank to the chainstay is an approach favored by some. I don't tend to do it on carbon frames.
As for putting a carbon crank in a vise: A lot of carbon cranks don't give you much in terms of parallel surfaces to work with. Solve that problem and use a jaw cover that won't damage the surface (like a rubberized soft jaw) and it's probably fine as long as you can do what you need to do clamping it firmly but not excessively. In practice though when doing this kind of thing with vice jaws going directly on to a crank arm, it's very easy to wind up struggling with only getting two small points of contact because the crank has a rounded, tapering profile, and rigging it up so a lot of force can go through it gets difficult. One could imagine making a 2-piece wood form or something go in the vise to pair with it if you really needed to.

Thanks. I don't think I can get my hands on this tool. If I understand correctly, SRAM has a spindle attached to the left so it won't be easy to attach anything on it. The immediate plan is to switch my cleats to SPD and let a bike shop do it after I come for a shock service (which will not take too long).

@VladimirFГероямслава Added an edit.

Before you take your crank to the vice, try the following backyard-mechanic method. I am yet to discover a pedal that cannot be removed this way.
Disclaimer
This method only works for pedals that have internal hex socket in the spindle and is only efficient for bikes with lever-operated rear brake.
Step 1
Stand, kneel or crouch on the bicycle side opposite to the one where pedal in question is. E.g: if undoing right, drive side pedal, stand on the left, non-drive side of the bike. From your position you should be able to clealry see the socket on the pedal axle
Step 2
Rotate the crank arm in question into a position pointing downwards and a bit forward. No need to be precise, this can be adjusted later
Step 3
Insert a hex wrench into pedal socket with the handle pointing towards the rear of the bike. Adjust the position of the crank arm to make the hex wrench handle as close as possible to horizontal
Step 4
Firmly press rear brake lever. Place your palm on the saddle and apply gentle pressure.
Step 5
Step on the handle of the hex wrench. If needed bounce a bit. If you get wheel spin, shift into higher gear.
Left pedal:

Right pedal:


I would add a second disclaimer that this should only be tried with a good quality hex wrench and good quality pedals. There's a risk of having the wrench slip out of the pedal (potentially damaging both) due to the large amount of bending force involved (in addition to just applying torque). Accordingly, you should ensure that the hex wrench fits snugly into the pedal before using this technique.
